# Is it possible to create a type-safe function that receives a callback and the callback's params with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a function that receives two arguments: a callback function, and the parameters (props) for that function. For example:

```js
const callbackFunction = (a: number) => a + 2;
const callbackFunctionProps = 5;
callbackWrapper(callbackFunction, callbackFunctionProps);
```

I want TypeScript to check that the props given as 'callbackFunctionProps' are valid props for 'callbackFunction'. Is there a way to do this without using generics? it does not matter what are the types of the function and props as long as they fit each other.

Comment: Without using generics...?

Comment: "It does not matter what are the types...." requirement does not go really well with "...without generics". Is there any reason not to use generics we should be aware of?

Comment: Both @raina77  and Majed Badawi answears worked great for me. Thank you for your help. I think what i was missing that you can always call a generic typed function without specifing the type and typescript will try to infer it.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are exactly the remedy for "it does not matter what are the types" cases. Here's one possible way to do that *with* generics:

```
const callbackWrapper = <I extends Array<unknown>, O>(fn: (...fnArgs: I) => O, ...args: I): O => 
{
    const result = fn(...args);
    console.log(`CALLED WITH ${args.join(', ')}, RESULT IS ${result}`);
    return result;
}

const callbackFunctionA = (a: number) => a + 2; 
const callbackFunctionPropsA = 5;

const callbackFunctionB = (a: number, b: number) => a + b + 2;
const callbackFunctionPropsB1 = 10;
const callbackFunctionPropsB2 = 30;

callbackWrapper(callbackFunctionA, callbackFunctionPropsA); 
// "CALLED WITH 5, RESULT IS 7" 
callbackWrapper(callbackFunctionB, callbackFunctionPropsB1, callbackFunctionPropsB2);
// "CALLED WITH 10, 30, RESULT IS 42"
```

The trick is using `I` (type-param of created generic) in two places: as a type of passed function's param (`...fnArgs: I` part) and as a type of params passed into your callback (`...args: I` part). If they do not match, the compiler will yell at you:

```
callbackWrapper(callbackFunctionA, '2'); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
callbackWrapper(callbackFunctionA, 2, 3); // Expected 2 arguments, but got 3.
callbackWrapper(callbackFunctionB, 2); // Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function callbackWrapper<T extends any[]>(
  callbackFunction: (...arg: T) => any,
  ...callbackFunctionProps: T
) {
  console.log(callbackFunction(...callbackFunctionProps));
}

function callbackFunction1(a: number) {
  return a + 2;
}
const callbackFunctionProps1 = 5;
callbackWrapper(callbackFunction1, callbackFunctionProps1);

function callbackFunction2(a: string) {
  return a + ' world';
}
const callbackFunctionProps2 = 'hello';
callbackWrapper(callbackFunction2, callbackFunctionProps2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay! Is there a way to not limit the type of `callbackFunction`  and `callbackFunctionProps`? To let `callbackWrapper` to be called with any function and function props, and make typescript verify that the given callback props fit the callback function? maybe even without generics, just infering from usage?

Comment: Ah got it, you want to match the callback parameter with the passed one